# Editing and saving is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an application in AngularJS with edit, save and cancel options, but the problem is that when I click the edit I am not getting the value for editing and saving.

The textfield and dropdowns are been provided through `ng-transclude`

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T6rA9/)**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl">
    <h2>Editors</h2>
    <span ng-repeat="location in location">
    <div class="field">
        <strong>State:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.state"><input ng-model="view.editableValue"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <strong>City:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.city"><select ng-model="view.editableValue" ng-options="loc.city for loc in location"></select></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <strong>Neighbourhood:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.neighbourhood"><input ng-model="view.editableValue"/></div>
    </div>
    <h2>Values</h2>
    <p><strong>State:</strong> {{location.state}}</p>
    <p><strong>City:</strong> {{location.city}}</p>
    <p><strong>Neighbourhood:</strong> {{location.neighbourhood}}</p>
    <hr>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know why, I was just playing around with the code, but seems working, at least with the text fields, using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`/`ng-hide`: http://jsfiddle.net/T6rA9/1/

I'll update my answer if I find a reason...

**Update**: I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/T6rA9/7/

The difference is that instead of saving the value on save, I am reverting the changes on cancel, which is easier due to angular two-way data-binding.

Because of that, I also removed the view.editableValue `ng-model` directive and used the fields as you would normally do.

Comment: works fine..... but why `$scope.selectableCities = [ "San Francisco", "Kollam" ];`

Comment: Because if you get the select options from the locations array that you are editing, when you change one location it becomes the same that the one that you selected, and the select options become: San Francisco | San Francisco (for example). That's why you need to store them statically.

Answer (score 1):

Transclusion and isolated scopes does not work the way you may think. You can read more about it here http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

If you i.e. make this change you will already see a difference

```
<div click-to-edit="location.state"><input ng-model="location.state"/></div>
```

Comment: so is there any solution for this

Comment: Sure, but I unfortunately don't have the time to elaborate on it right now.

Comment: the how about this http://fiddle.jshell.net/vXEyz/, here i am able to access the controller variable value within  the transclude scope

Comment: I suggest creating hidden fields/inputs and showing them after clicking certain button (as I did in my example). It shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating ngClick function which add input element inside your div with previous value?

```
<div class="newInput" ng-show="hidden">
   <label> {{ inputValue }} </label>
</div>

<div class="newInput" ng-show="!hidden">
  <input ng-model="inputValue" />
</div>
```

And main.js file:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.hidden = true;

  $scope.inputValue = 'Edit me!';

  $scope.addInput = function() {
    $scope.hidden = !$scope.hidden;
  }

});
```

Here you have [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tq8QGL7cWAcbZh6gqgQj?p=preview)

Comment: can you show me that with the above example within a fiddle

Comment: Sure. Try something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/tq8QGL7cWAcbZh6gqgQj?p=preview

Comment: see @emilio have solved the textfield issue...now the problem is with the select http://jsfiddle.net/T6rA9/1/